# In Python, how do you color a graph?

Tags: python, r

I want to know how to colour the vertices of a graph in R or python, the RGBL Rpackage doesn't work, could you provide me with some helpful suggestions?

I want to color a graph that i constructed.
Graph coloring is the procedure of assignment of colors to each vertex of a graph G such that no adjacent vertices get same color

Comment: Try [igraph](https://igraph.org/). In R, try package [`igraph`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=igraph). What have you tried? Can you post minimal data and code showing what didn't work?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I'm not sure what command can help us color our graph with @igraph.